# show and hide between 2 different component Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have `Parent` component with 2 different `child`, `inquiryForm` and `inquiryResponse`, I got situation when I need to hide and show this 2 component based on condition:

- If user had click `submit` on `inquiryForm`, it will **hide** `inquiryForm` component and **show** `inquiryResponse` component
- On `inquiryResponse` component, there are `button` `display inquiry form`, where user clicked it and will **hide** `inquiryResponse` component and **show** `inquiryForm`.**I cant solved this.**
- I know it can be solved using `router` but I want different solution like using `service` or `subject`

this is demo I created using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lntwns?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.html), this is what I had tried;

**inquiry-response.ts**

```
  getReceivedSummons() {
    this.inquiryStore.summons$.subscribe(result => {
      this.receivedSummon = result;
      this.addCheckboxes();
      this.isShowResponse = true;
    });
  }

    showInquiryForm() {
    // do something
    }
```

**inquiry-response.html**

```
<div *ngIf="isShowResponse">
  <p>Inquiry Response</p>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitSelectedCheckboxes()">
  <ng-container formArrayName="receivedSummons" *ngFor="let summon of formReceivedSummons.controls; let i = index">
    <ng-container [formGroup]="summon">
      <ng-container formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of formReceivedSummonsItems(i).controls; let j = index">
        <ng-container [formGroup]="item">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked"> {{item.value.name}}
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <div *ngIf="!summon.valid">At least one order must be selected</div>
  </ng-container>
  <br>
  <span class="button">
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
  </span>
  <button (click)="showInquiryForm()"> ( change ID number ) display inquiry form</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use `*ngIf`?

Comment: use ngif on the parent, use `@Output()` to communicate from child to parent when component should be hidden: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

As AJT_82 say, you app.component can be like

```
<app-inquiry-form *ngIf="step==1" (submit)="step=2"></app-inquiry-form>
<br>
<app-inquiry-response *ngIf="step==2" (click)="step=1"></app-inquiry-response>

//you has a variable
step:number=1;
```

And in each component

```
  @Output() submit=new EventEmitter<any>()
  ..in somewhere...
  this.submit.emit()

  @Output() click=new EventEmitter<any>()
  ..in somewhere...
  this.click.emit()
```